# OH-TFS-Connector-0030 OpsHub-012300 #OpsHub

Tags: opshub

Trying to migrate to VSO and I'm getting this error. I can see all the changeset up to 30, but it's saying that I haven't got read to changeset 40. Didn't know that you could set permissions on specific changesets?

Error in execution of Job : tfs.my-server.com\DefaultCollection to my-server.visualstudio.com| tfs.my-server.com\DefaultCollection to my-server.visualstudio.com| TFS Source 1426530642910 Source TFS 1426530642910 'eHub' Commit Information  tfs.my-server.com\DefaultCollection to my-server.visualstudio.com| TFS Source 1426530642910 Source TFS 1426530642910 TFS Commit Information
OpsHub-012300: Error occurred in generating events. Caused by Error in getting All Change Events : OH-TFS-Connector-0030: Error occurred in executing operation getTotalRevisions. Server Error : TF14098: Access Denied: User Joe Bloggs needs Read permission(s) for at least one item in changeset 44.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance that Changeset **44** had file changes committed across project. Like a file of Project A is renamed and file of Project B is deleted. And those pend changes are committed together as one changeset.

And now, you are migrating **only** Project A with a user who does **not** have permission to view/access Project B. Hence, the issue.

Try using a user with Administrator privilege or providing your current user with access to whichever the other project is in changeset 44.